# Android Push notification without google play services

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, mqtt

Requirement: I am looking for a (open-source/free-to-use) mechanism:

- to deliver messages (similar to GCM) to android clients which do not require google play service/store on client side.
- Support for more than 10,000 concurrent clients.
- Support for sending messages to individual client, group of clients or all clients.
- Only authorized entity (can be another server) should be able to send/publish messages.
- Support for "only data" messages i.e. message need not be shown in notification bar. It will be consumed by client app for its own operations (e.g. perform some action based on data, display in-app notification, etc).

I have explored some MQTT based solutions (e.g. rabbitMQ) but didn't find any recent documentation/tutorial for android based client.

Let me know any solution which can satisfy my requirement.

Comment: Requests for software/service recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow, please use https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [UnifiedPush](https://unifiedpush.org/). They even want to be the open-source pendant to GCM.

An Alternative could also be [Gotify](https://gotify.net/).

Comment: I have checked Gotify. I think it does not support some features like individual or group messaging. I will update this in question. UnifiedPush looks promising solution. I will check whether it satisfies all my requirements.